# Converting from XML to a C++ Object

Tags: c++, xml

I'm working on a C++ project, and wanted to get some inputs from developers with similar experience.

The task is to connect to a web service which gives the results in an XML form. My role in the task is once I receive the XML form, I need to convert the XML into a C++ object and parse the XML data to the C++ object.

Following are my clarifications.

a) One way is to handcraft the whole thing but I need to do this for around hundreds of web services. I am aware there are simpler tools for C# and Java to do the same.

Is there a tool/utility for C++ too?

Any suggestions, would be helpful.

Comment: When you say you need to convert the XML into a C++ object what exactly do you mean?  It sounds like you're looking for a C++ XML parser?  There are a quite a few of those, if this is what you're looking for I can suggest some.  I've used RapidXML recently and was quite happy with it.  Also used Xerces in the past.

Comment: @Guy sounds like he is looking for an IoC container, which can be created by reading a xml file.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used TinyXML for my XML parsing needs. My parsing code operated under the assumption that all XML input conforms to a particular XSD schema I wrote. It worked fairly well but the ripple effects were annoying - if I wanted to change the XSD, I had to update all my XML test files as well as my parsing code. While it's not so bad in the case of parsing one schema, I'd hate to have to do it for hundreds of them.

I'm not sure what the common solution is, but [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) sounds pretty promising. I haven't used it, but it appears that it generates a data layer, a parser and serialisation code for you. Could save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if there's a way to dynamically create an object representation of an XML data stream (such that you can access it like topLevel.subObject.value), it's not possible. C++ is a statically-typed language, which means all objects need to be defined a compile time. The best you could do is something like: xmlData.getSubObject("objectName").getValue().

As for toolsets for parsing into something usable dynamically (as per my later example), there are several. For Windows, for example, you could use the "built-in" MSXML objects. There's nothing in the base C++ libraries to do so, however, as far as I am aware.

Hope that helps.